# what is the difference between df[1] and df[,1] (in dataframes)

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

i've noticed they give the same result except that for df[1] it gives the column in the shape of a dataframe while df[,1] returns a vector.Also, i've noticed they give exactly the same result in tibbles.  is that all it is to it  ?

Comment: See `help(Extract)` for all of the fun ways `[` differs for every object type. There is also `[[` and `$` to consider.

Comment: `df[,1, drop=FALSE]` is identical to `df[1]` (they both give a data.frame) while `df[,1]` is identical to `df[[1]]` (they both give an atomic vector if the column is not a list column).  The tibble gives the same result because tibble uses `drop=FALSE` as the default.

Answer (score 0):

The "[" function has (at least) two different forms. When used on a dataframe which is a special form of a list with two  arguments it returns the contents of the rows and columns specified columns. It does have an optional argument "drop" whose default is TRUE. If it is set to FALSE, then you get the subset as a dataframeWhen used with one argument, it returns the columns itself without loss of the "data.frame" class attribute. The columns are actually lists in their own right.

The other extraction function, "[[" also returns the contents only.

```
dat <- data.frame(A=1:10,B=letters[1:10])

> str(dat[1:5,])
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ B: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
> str(dat[1:5,1])
 int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
> str(dat[1])
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ A: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> str(dat[[1]])
 int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> str(dat[,1,drop=FALSE])
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ A: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```